# NSFetchedResultsController update/insert removing cell from UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Using `NSFetchedResultsController` to auto update `UITableview` but facing some issue. When trying to add/edit from another device the whole cell is vanished every time.

Here is the bunch of code

```
// NSFetchedResultsController Delegate methods

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.aTableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.aTableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0"))
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            else
                [tableView reloadData];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.aTableView endUpdates];
}

// Fetch data from coredata

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)loadForumData {

if (_fetchedForumController != nil) {
    return _fetchedForumController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SocialWall" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateTime" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eventId == %@)",self.appDelegate.currentEvent.entityId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

fetchRequest.fetchLimit = _range+10;
fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 0; // start range

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
[theFetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

_fetchedForumController = theFetchedResultsController;
[_fetchedForumController performFetch:nil];
return _fetchedForumController;

}
```

Here is the o/p what i'm getting on device/simulator after editing the cell . Please check the attached simulator screenshort - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUMPh.png

Comment: @zylenv following the guideline from raywenderlich, link is -  https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: @zylenv and even from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Comment: Yeah, you are right!